# how to list photos by hashtags

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to make an app that list photos in a specific hashtag and i will print them for an organization. But i can't do it in sandbox mode(Restrictions) and instagram doesn't let me to go live with this explanation.

"We do not approve the public_content permission for one-off projects such as displaying hashtag based content on your website. As alternative solution, you can show your own Instagram content, or find a company that offers this type of service (content discover, moderation, and display)."

Is there any solution to do?

Comment: just use instagram.com to search for hashtag and print, or use other 3rd party service like http://www.picodash.com to search+filter and display for printing

Comment: i need a 3rd party service that offers me an api to list photos. i will develop a web application. picodash is not the thing i want. do you know any other service like this?

Comment: instagram is the only one who can give API to build web app, if not u have use a 3rd party service